# Sending order email when pragmatically updating an order

Tags: magento-enterprise, programmatically

I am building a custom payment gateway for my Magento EE 1.14.0.1 website. My issue is on the payment processing page I need to be able to have Magento send the customer the sales order confirmation email. However my php code does not seem to work meaning it is not sending any email out. Although it is doing everything else I need it to do.

Below is my code

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$order->addStatusHistoryComment("Credit Card approved transaction ID $gatetranid")
    ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
    ->setIsCustomerNotified(true);

$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
//$order->setEmailSent(true);
$order->save();
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                            ->addObject($invoice)
                                            ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

 $transactionSave->save();  
 $invoice->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::STATE_PAID)->save();

  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsQuoteId();
  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
```

The above code makes a comment on the order creates an invoice and marks it as paid all which work well. the only part that does not seem to be working is the
$order->sendNewOrderEmail(); code??

Email is working as I put a simple php mail() line of code on the page and it sent me an email. I also changed the ->setIsCustomerNotified(false); to be ->setIsCustomerNotified(true);

however still not able to receive the sales order confirmation email. 
Any other suggestions?
I looked at the system and exceptions logs in var/log and that did not show any errors?

However I am thinking the section of code I might have wrong is

```
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
   $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
   $order->addStatusHistoryComment("Credit Card approved transaction ID $gatetranid")
      ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
      ->setIsCustomerNotified(true);
   $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
```

Comment: `->setIsCustomerNotified(false);` try setting to `true` ?

Comment: Did you check to make sure email is working? Is your cron setup?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
//$order->setEmailSent(true);
$order->save();
```

to

```
//$order->setEmailSent(true);
$order->save();
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself or is it just a suggestion? Can you justify why this would work better than what's originally done?

Comment: Thanks, none of the suggests seem to work and I am totally stumped on why.